# OpenVPN client tun device name in OSX

Tags: macos, vpn, dns, openvpn

I have a VPN server set up that I am using to connect to from my OSX 10.9 laptop. When I load my openvpn profile with tunnelblick, it works, and I get a device named "tun0" just like you would expect.

When I use openvpn commandline to load the file, I get a device named "utun0" and the connection doesn't work as expected. The main thing I notice is that the dhcp DNS option does not work, and I don't get my new DNS server installed in /etc/resolve.conf

Can anyone explain to me what I may be doing wrong with the command line version?

Comment: Tunnelblick includes several scripts that get called after a VPN is established.  They are what handles the DHCP.  The OpenVPN binary itself doesn't do anything with the DHCP settings.  You should take some time and review the Tunnelblick scripts.  Or to say it differently, you are expecting OpenVPN to do things that it doesn't handle.

Comment: i see what you mean now. This explains why the DNS option wasn't working. If you write this up as an answer I will accept it